# Sagepay; No shopping basket provided

Tags: omnipay

Am using Omnipay with the Paypal and Sagepay gateways. Got it working well, all for except one area - the setItems basket!

I am using the setItems method and adding my name, descriptions and qty for each line item before I send my purchase request.

Works fine with Paypal, however Sagepay does nothing? When I log into Sagepay and view the transaction I just see 'No shopping basket provided'. I assume this does not work for Sagepay then?

Thanks, Dean.

Comment: Give me a hour or two - I am just testing a PR to support adding an XML basket.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there is no support for shopping basket items in the omnipay-sagepay gateway. That's not to say that you couldn't add that support if it's supported by SagePay but there is not any current support for it in Omnipay.

Answer (score 0):

The dev-master branch of https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-sagepay now supports the basket (aka items). It supports negative item prices, which appear in the basket as discounts.

Be aware that the costs in the live Sage Pay gateway *should* add up to the total cost being authorised. I say "should" because the documentation says it must, but the test gateway does not enforce this, so I'm not sure whether the live gateway enforces this either.

I have a few more tests to add, then will make an omnipay-sagepay release with the XML basket support.